# cakephp 4 - model without database

Tags: cakephp

In a cakephp 4 project in need to read data from a third party api.

I found this doc for cakephp 2, but no equivalent for cakephp 4.
https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/models/datasources.html

Where is it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Read data from a third part api direct in your controller using HttpClient or other libs.

https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/core-libraries/httpclient.html

Comment: I'd like to share the logic between a controller and some commands so perhaps a datasource is a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In CakePHP 4 the ORM is structured quite differently, data is retrieved via a Datasource, so you essentially need an HTTP-backed Datasource.

While CakePHP doesn't naively supply an HTTP source, there are a few of plugins that do, such as:

- https://github.com/imsamurai/cakephp-httpsource-datasource
- https://github.com/CakePHP-Copula/Copula

It looks like these may have some drawbacks and limitations - and in general be fairly advanced setups requiring some creative problem solving. So in the end, as the other poster mentioned, it may in the end be easier to just make HTTP requests directly if you don't require any of the ORM features (validation, Entity classes, virtual fields, Event hooks, etc.)

Comment: ok thanks for your advice. I'll do that. 
Is there  a solution to share code between controller and commands ?

Comment: Generally you're welcome to create independent classes that don't fit Cake's existing conventions - an API library class outside the Controller would qualify I think (I keep my internal libraries in src/Lib). If it's small, a single class with the HTTP Client calls inside would work. The Controller & Command could each call the API library independently. If it's complicated, you could follow a Service Factory Pattern like https://github.com/constantcontact/php-sdk does, just using Cake HTTP Clients. For the data it returns, optionally you can marshal Entity classes (implement EntityInterface).

Answer (score 0):

If the API communicate using POST/GET requests and responds using JSON format (which is usually the case), you can use the [Request & Response Objects](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/controllers/request-response.html) to ask and get data from the API

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).